# file name as argument and sort in descending way in perl?

Tags: scripting, perl

I have this perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
open my $df, '<', 'file.txt' or die "open: $!\n";
my %h;
while (<$df>) {
    $h{$_}++ for split /\s+/;
    END{
        for (keys %h){
            print $_, "=", $h{$_};
            print "\n";
        }
     } 
}
```

it prints the occurrence of each word  in the file, I have several questions

1) How can I make this script dynamic by let the user put one argument as a file name

Now:

```
perl script.pl
```

wanted:

```
perl script.pl fileName
```

2) How can I sort the output in descending way?

NOTE: I want the sort according to the occurrence.

Comment: @don_crissti, It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my %h;
while (<>) {
    $h{$_}++ for split /\s+/;
    END{
        for (sort { $h{$b} <=> $h{$a} } keys %h){
            print $_, "=", $h{$_};
            print "\n";
        }
     }
}
```

so :

```
./script input_file
```

Comment: Corrected sort things, seems to be what's op want

Comment: It doesn't actually matter, but that `END` block inside the `while` is giving me the heebie-jeebies.